# Ocultar componente fora do router-viewer

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estou usando o `Vue Rotuer` para controlar as rotas do meu projeto, com isso, vi a necessidade de utilizar `Navigation Guards`.

```
<script>
    export default{
        beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next){
            if(to.meta.adminOnly === false){
                //alert('f')
                next()
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Ate ai tudo otimo, porem, vi uma dificuldade, por se tratar de um `dashboard`, eu tenho a pagina de `login` e as outras paginas. Na minha pagina `app.vue` tenho a seguinte estrutura.

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <Menu></Menu>
        <router-view class="containerView"></router-view>
    </div>
</template>
```

O componente `Menu` tem todo o meu menu lateral e superior, pois quero que ao mudar de pagina, ele permanessa e só os conteudo se alterem, por isso deixei fora do `<router-view></router-view>`.

Porem, estou com dificuldade para oculta-lo, caso meu usuario não esteja logado (esteja na pagina de login), e não consegui resolver, eu tentei utilizar o `beforeRouterEnter` na pagina `app.vue` para validar em que pagina o usuario está e se a pagina contem o `meta adminOnly`, porem não deu certo, e não queria usar `localStorage` para fazer essa validação, porque o mesmo, manteria meu sistema inseguro de mais.

Comment: Não podes fazer uma chamada ajax dentro do `beforeRouteEnter` para verificar se a sessão é válida? Talvez não tenha percebido bem, mas a verificação é contra o servidor certo?

Comment: @Sergio Eu ainda vou fazer essa validação com o servidor, mas mesmo assim, como iria ocultar meu `Menu`:? e a chamada `ajax`, ficaria em cada `beforeRouteEnter`?

Comment: Podes ter uma variável/flag que guarda o estado em memória. Terias de fazer o ajax uma vez. Depois podes querer ter uma lógica de timeout de inatividade, mas a flag iria funcionar por sessão. Parece parecido ao que queres?

Comment: Sim, mas como funcionaria? como eu criaria uma `sessão`? e esse `sessão` eu conseguiria executar de qualquer um dos meus arquivos? e se o usuario atualizar a pagina por algum motivo, iria se manter logado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ferramentas que o vue-router dispõe são:

- beforeEach
- campos `meta`

Configura cada rota que precisa de autentificação com `meta: { requiresAuth: true }`. Podes colocar isso no `children` como está na documentação:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/foo',
      component: Foo,
      children: [
        {
          path: 'bar',
          component: Bar,
          // a meta field
          meta: { requiresAuth: true }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

Depois verificas isso antes de cada rota. O `beforeEach` passa o `to` que é a rota que foi pedida. Aí podes verificar se essa rota precisa de autorização. Caso precise e não esteja logado, faz redirect para a página de login.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    // this route requires auth, check if logged in
    // if not, redirect to login page.
    if (!auth.loggedIn()) {
      next({
        path: '/login',
        query: { redirect: to.fullPath }
      })
    } else {
      next()
    }
  } else {
    next() // make sure to always call next()!
  }
})
```

A parte de guardar a informação de estar logado ou não há maneiras diferentes. Podes guardar só numa variável com estado `true|false`, via `localStorage` etc.

Há um video sobre isso útil: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2yc_ACcMA0

Comment: Sergio, me perdooe minha ignorancia, mas o que é `variavel de estado`? acho que no localStorage, fica vuneravel, pois uma pessoa pode ir e colocar lá como `true`, ai tem acesso a todo o sistema.

Comment: @RafaelAugusto não te importes com não saber. É por isso que o site existe. Lamento não poder responder mais rápido. Então, a ideia dessa variável de estado é na sua versão mais simples algo como `let autenticado = true;`. Bem simples. Em JavaScript nunca podes garantir que a aplicação não é manipulada, por isso sugiro que o servidor tenha controlo de sessão para não enviar dados para o cliente caso o login não tenha sido feito. Podias usar lazy-loading caso os componentes tenham de ter dados quando carregam https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/lazy-loading.html

Comment: Sergio, o que é esse `path` e `component` ?

Comment: Sergio, eu consegui entender agora, valeu pela ajuda, acho que isso me fez compreender já como esconder o componente, e entender ainda mais a estrutura do `vue`, agora a validação fica comigo, abraços

Comment: @RafaelAugusto ótimo. Eu ainda estou no trabalho por isso não pude responder, mas ótimo teres descoberto. Se tiveres mais duvidas pergunta que eu ajudo quando puder.

Comment: Sergio, me tira uma duvida (caso você ache que devo postar uma pergunta para isso, pode dizer que eu posto), seguindo isso que me falou, o meu Menu é um componente, como passaria um valor para ele? sendo que chamo meu componente `Menu` no `App.vue` e não no `Dashboard.vue`